# Array of char * as argument in c

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to pass an array of char * defined with braces and with static strings, and I want to pass it as an argument to a function.

The array is the next:

```
char * phrase[] = {"my", "name", "is", "John"};
```

and the function which is going to receive the argument is implemented as follows:

```
void composeList(char * phrase[]){
  //I'm getting the size of the list
  int phrase_list_size = sizeof(*phrase)/sizeof(phrase[0]);
  printf("%d\n",phrase_list_size);
}
```

I call that function in this way:

```
composeList(phrase);
```

But when I print the size the value is 1 instead of 4. Could you help me?

Comment: An array decays into a pointer when is passed to a function, and thats what you get inside the function: the size of a pointer.

Comment: @Fredrik both values are 4 on a 32bit system or 8 on a 64bit system.

Comment: I want to know the number of items. sizeof(*phrase) returns the number of chars in the array. I obtained the operation from a Stackoverflow post. And it runs when i do that in the main functions.

Comment: Use a function like this: `void composeList(char * phrase[], size_t size);` and call it like this: `composeList(phrase, sizeof(*phrase)/sizeof(phrase[0]));`

Comment: Another tip is to use always use `-Wall` and `-Wextra` when compiling. In this case it will warn about your problem